# HuggingFace LLM with LangChain response truncated

Tags: huggingface-transformers, langchain, large-language-model

I'm working on a basic example using LangChain and HuggingFace's LLMs. So far I can make requests, but it seems like they're being truncated before the response is sent to my system. Here's what I have so far...

```
from langchain.llms import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.schema.output_parser import StrOutputParser

repo_id = 'HuggingFaceH4/zephyr-7b-alpha'


template = """Answer the question.

Question: {question}
"""
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)

llm = HuggingFaceHub(
    repo_id=repo_id, 
    model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.5, "use_cache": False},
    huggingfacehub_api_token=HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN
)

chain = (
    {"question": RunnablePassthrough()} 
    | prompt 
    | llm 
    | StrOutputParser()
)

chain.invoke("Write a rap battle between Stephen Colbert and John Oliver")
```

The response I get is `'\nStephen Colbert:\n(To the beat)\nYo, John Oliver, you'`. No matter the prompt I use the response is truncated, and I've tried this with other LLMs on Hugging Face. I subclassed LangChain's HuggingFaceHub class to add some logging and it does seem like the response I receive stops there but I haven't been able to get an answer that's longer than this. Are there different parameters I need to send to the model?